# Searching API but cant get full list to show on REACT.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So im making a website to search through different games. I was able to make it search the ApI based on the title but now I cant get the full list to show anymore without having to type for a title of game. I guess my question is how can I show the full list always and if you wanted to search for the game it will just show for the game the user searched.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Games = () => {
  const [games, setGames] = React.useState([]);
  const [search, setsearch] = React.useState("");

  const axios = require("axios");

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/api/games`,
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "8145a0d66fmsh967b9729537d0f7p1aaab0jsncb9dccfb2e32",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  axios
    .request(options)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

  const getGames = async () => {
    let response = await axios.request(options);
    console.log(response.data);
    setGames(response.data);
  };

  React.useEffect(function () {
    getGames();
  }, []);

  const searchGame = (event) => {
    setsearch(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-games">
      <input
        className="search"
        type="text"
        value={search}
        onChange={searchGame}
        placeholder="Enter game here..."
      />
      {games
        .filter((item) => {
          const searchTerm = search.toLowerCase();
          const title = item.title.toLowerCase();

          return searchTerm && title.startsWith(searchTerm);
        })
        .map(function (game) {
          return (
            <Link
              className="main-games-layout"
              key={game.id}
              to={`/games/${game.id}`}
            >
              <img src={game.thumbnail} alt="game picture" />
              <br />
              <h3>{game.title}</h3>
              <br />
              {game.short_description}
            </Link>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Games;
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
.filter((item) => {
  const searchTerm = search.toLowerCase();
  const title = item.title.toLowerCase();

  return searchTerm && title.startsWith(searchTerm);
})
```

you're requiring `searchTerm` to be truthy in order for the callback to return true - and for anything to be rendered. Invert that test so that *either* there's no search term, or the title starts with it.

```
return !searchTerm || title.startsWith(searchTerm);
```

Comment: wow what an easy fix I can kiss you right now. Thank you!